# Grand Total Calculation in Javascript to handle currency format (MinusSignNegative)

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have a javascript code below that calculates a grand total into a read only text field when dealing with currency formats i.e. $500.00. The problem that I am running into is how to handle the calculation when more than one negative number is entered in currency format (MinusSignNegative) i.e. ($500.00) instead of -$500.00. I am currently getting a NaN error in the grand total.

I believe that this regex should handle it but I can't figure out how to implement. http://www.regexlib.com/(X(1)A(bk8AHOFYowt7XHOC4WUCtfdM2LhlaovTNInhWLTrzAeoeq-c53XkkdwLD-WDe3OgQtJ7BLHSs0P-u-RrLbfVZaQIHkBH2exYGw0qtz6nqSamZNVqtnyufo9Y3nrEq5mq-mry63HY4Nnv0dfsQOZzKvuwcKAuwigyyQva-67laxr-ModxTQESW8fXx2XJL_0L0))/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=625&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Can anybody offer a solution?

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    <!--
    function total(what,number) {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<number;i++) {
           if (what.elements['price' + i].value.replace(/\$|\,/g,'') == '')
               what.elements['price' + i].value.replace(/\$|\,/g,'') == '0.00';
           grandTotal += (what.elements['price' + i].value.replace(/\$|\,/g,'') - 0);
        }
        what.grandTotal.value = (Math.round(grandTotal*100)/100);
        }
    //-->
    </SCRIPT>

    <FORM NAME="myName">
    Tax Due/Refund: <input TYPE="text" NAME="price0" VALUE="" SIZE="10" class='currency' onChange="total(this.form,3)"><BR>
    Interest: <input TYPE="text" NAME="price1" VALUE="" SIZE="10" class='currency' onChange="total(this.form,3)"><BR>
    Penalty: <input TYPE="text" NAME="price2" VALUE="" SIZE="10" class='currency' onChange="total(this.form,3)"><BR>
    Total Amount Assessed: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="grandTotal" class='currency' SIZE="25" READONLY="readyonly" style="background:#eee none; color:#222; font-weight:bold">
    </FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with or without that regex.

Without:

```
fieldValue = field.value; // "(500.00)"
// search for a "(" char
if (fieldValue.indexOf("(") >= 0) {
    // remove all chars, but numbers and dots
    fieldValue = fieldValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/ig, "");
    // 500.00
    numberFieldValue = Number(fieldValue) * -1;
}
```

With:

```
fieldValue = field.value; // "(500.00)"
// test if the value matches that pattern for negative numbers
if (fieldValue.match(/PUT_THAT_REGEX_HERE/g)) {
    // remove all chars, but numbers and dots
    fieldValue = fieldValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/ig, "");
    // 500.00
    numberFieldValue = Number(fieldValue) * -1;
}
```

it should look like this:

```
function total(what,number) {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<number;i++) {

        fieldValue = what.elements['price' + i].value; // "(500.00)" 
        // search for a "(" char 
        if (fieldValue.indexOf("(") >= 0) { 
            // remove all chars, but numbers and dots 
            fieldValue = fieldValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/ig, ""); 
            // 500.00 
            numberFieldValue = Number(fieldValue) * -1; 
        } else if (fieldValue.replace(/\$|\,/g,'') == '') {
            numberFieldValue = 0;
        } else {
            numberFieldValue = number(fieldValue.replace(/\$|\,/g,''));
        }

        grandTotal += numberFieldValue ;
    }
    what.grandTotal.value = (Math.round(grandTotal*100)/100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but how can I work this solution into the function total code I listed above?

Comment: You can put this part inside the `for` loop, just above that if clause, change `field.value` for `what.elements['price' + i].value` and use the variable `fieldValue` instead of `what.elements['price' + i].value` on the other lines.

Comment: Please see my edit to your question. Should the code look like that? I am still getting the NaN error with that code.

Comment: This code is giving me a function expected error when I plug a value into the fields and the grandTotal is not populated.

Comment: Please, make a http://jsfiddle.net with your code, so I can take a look on what is happening. BTW, you don't code. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to move a negative sign from the number to the left of a dollar sign,
do it when you write the total value field.

```
function total(what, number){
    var grandTotal= 0,  i= number, val, sign;
    while(i){
        val= what.elements['price' + i--].value.replace([$, ]+/g,'') ;
        grandTotal+= parseFloat(val) || 0;
    }
    sign= grandTotal<0? '-' :'';
    what.grandTotal.value=  sign+'$'+ Math.abs(Math.round(grandTotal*100)/100);
}
```

Comment: He wants to sum the values of all fields, but some of them have that format e.g. `($500.00)`